# Python: I have a list of words, and want to check the number of occurrences of those words in each line in a file

Tags: python, regex

So I want to count the occurrences of certain words, per line, in a text file. How many times each specific word occurred doesnt matter, just how many times any of them occurred per line.  I have a file containing a list of words, delimited by newline character. It looks like this:

```
amazingly
astoundingly
awful
bloody
exceptionally
frightfully
.....
very
```

I then have another text file containing lines of text. Lets say for example:

```
frightfully frightfully amazingly Male. Don't forget male
green flag stops? bloody bloody bloody bloody 
I'm biased.
LOOKS like he was headed very 
green flag stops?
amazingly exceptionally exceptionally
astoundingly
hello world
```

I want my output to look like:

```
3
4
0
1
0
3
1
```

Here's my code:

```
def checkLine(line):   
    count = 0
    with open("intensifiers.txt") as f:
        for word in f:
            if word[:-1] in line:
                count += 1
    print count


for line in open("intense.txt", "r"):
    checkLine(line)
```

Here's my actual output:

```
4
1
0
1
0
2
1
0
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
def checkLine(line):
    with open("intensifiers.txt") as fh:
        line_words = line.rstrip().split(' ')
        check_words = [word.rstrip() for word in fh]
        print sum(line_words.count(w) for w in check_words)


for line in open("intense.txt", "r"):
    checkLine(line)
```

Output:

```
3
4
0
1
0
3
1
0
```